# How to avoid empty instantiating of custom classes?

Tags: c#, oop, chess

I'm making a chess program, and I'm trying to optimize my code, wherein I have an abstract base class `ChessPiece` which has the basic properties `Board`, `Color`, and `StartPosition`. Now in this base class constructor is where I add the instantiated specific piece. Here is that part:

```
    // ChessPiece.cs
    protected ChessPiece(Square startPosition, PieceColor color, Board board)
    {
        this.StartPosition = startPosition;
        this.CurrentPosition = startPosition;
        this.Color = color;
        this.Board = board;
        this.Board[startPosition] = this;
        // ↑
        // I add the pieces inside the indexer assignment (e.g. pieces.Add(piece)...)
    }
```

Here is how I add the pieces in the `Board` class:

```
    //  Board.cs
    public ChessPiece this[Square square]
    {
        get { ... }
        set
        {
            //  simplified version of how I add pieces
            this._pieces.Add(value);
        }
    }
```

Now, I setup my board this way:

```
    // Game.cs
    private void PopulateBoard()
    {
        this.CreateStandardPieces(PieceColor.White);
        this.CreateStandardPieces(PieceColor.Black);
    }

    private void CreateStandardPieces(PieceColor color)
    {
        //  rook
        new Rook(aSquare, color, this.Board);
        //  more initializations here
    }
```

The sample instantiation `new Rook(...)` looks weird to me, like it is an empty instantiation. Whereas what actually happens is whenever I instantiate a piece, it is automatically added to the board, as opposed to looking an "empty instantiation".

Now my question is, how should I improve my design as to avoid instantiations to look like this?
Or, is this design accepted as a good OOP design?

**EDIT:**
added code on how I add the pieces

Answer (score 0):

You can see the board as one system and the pieces on it as sub systems. Its strange separation of concerns and coupling to let the subsystem know about the parent system and even mutate its state.

A cleaner way in my opinion is that the board adds the pieces (Or a system above the board).

Read up on `Separations of concerns` and `High cohesion – Low coupling`

edit: The piece should only hold info on how it can move on the board. Its up to the board or a system above the board to actually move it

Comment: I agree with this. That's exactly how I've setup the objects in the program.So any suggestions on how to avoid an "**empty instantiation**" or is this ok already as it is? I'm not quite satisfied with my design with regards to this.

Comment: You edited your question. But you still add the piece to the board from the piece this.Board[startPosition] = this;.

Comment: Let the piece do the moving on the board. In the move method supply it with a IBoard interface or similar

Comment: I see. What you mean is that I shouldn't add that line of code inside the ChessPiece class, am I right?

Comment: I dont think the pieces should have any direct knowledge about the board at all.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Looks like I'm gonna have a big refactoring of my code since I use the board as reference in many places in the program.

Comment: Better to refactor now than later! Good luck. Its fun to model games, since their domain is based on physical items not abstract concepts like in business apps.

Comment: I would claim that the board should not move the pieces at all. It should only provide information on the actual board. Moving chess pieces should be done by the player, as in real life. Rules on how can a piece move should be in an entirely different class for game rules. If you have the time, it's worth reading Eric Lippert 5 parts blog series called [Wizards and warriors.](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/)

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks for your input about the design. I'll definitely consider that. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :-)